# What is the grammatical role of emerging out?

Tags: grammar, meaning

What are the **grammatical role** and the **meaning** of "emerging out" in the following sentence?

> The most widely accepted theory, championed by anthropologists in the
>   late nineteenth and early twentieth centuries envisions theater as
>   **emerging out** of myth and ritual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**emerging** is the present participle of **emerge**.  The theater is envisioned as **emerging**, that is, as "coming out of" {somewhere}.

**out of myth and ritual** is a prepositional phrase which adds information that indicates the origin of the act of emerging, the "somewhere", just as we would say:

> The CEO emerged *from his office*.

In this theater example, **emerge** is used figuratively, since "myth and ritual" are not places, in the sense that "his office" is a place. Here it could be paraphrased as *developed from* or *arose from* or *grew out of*. In other words, theater was seen as originating in myth and ritual.

> He emerged from the darkness.
>
> The wolves emerged from the forest.
>
> The nurse's head emerged from the doorway. "Next!" she shouted.
>
> The candidate emerged from the pack as the nominee.
>
> Batman emerged out of the gloom and zipped up to the rooftop on a thin metal wire.

Stylistically, some speakers would say that **out of** is a little clumsy with **emerge**, as [this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=emerging%20from%2Cemerging%20out%20of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cemerging%20from%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cemerging%20out%20of%3B%2Cc0) attests.